# Duda al crear un TAD matriz genérico con plantillas en C++

Tags: c++, template

El ejercicio consistía en implementar las operaciones para un TAD matriz **no genérico**, una vez implementado todo correctamente, con ´templates´ hay que hacer el TAD matriz **genérico** y acepte cualquier dimensión valida de filas y columnas, a la vez que cualquier tipo de dato válido.

A continuación pongo el código resumido:

En la cabecera:

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define F 3
#define C 3


class Matriz
{
public:

  // Definición de las clases de excepciones
  class ECoordenadasIncorrectas: public std::runtime_error
  {
  public:
    ECoordenadasIncorrectas(const std::string& w = "ECoordenadasIncorrectas"): std::runtime_error(w) {}
  };

  // Declaración de la interfaz del TAD Matriz<E,F,C>

  Matriz();
  ~Matriz();

  void identidad();
  void ceros();
  void unos();
  void multiplicar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void sumar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void restar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void trasponer(Matriz& salida);
  int filas();
  int columnas();

  float valor(int i, int j);

  void asignar(int i, int j, float v);

  template <typename ModificaElemento>
  void modificar(ModificaElemento modifica_elemento);

  Matriz& operator=(Matriz& m);

  /** Constructor de copia */
  Matriz(Matriz& m);

  bool operator==(Matriz& m);
  bool operator!=(Matriz& m);

private:
  float elementos_[F][C];
};

#include "matriz.cpp"
#include "matriz_io.cpp"
#endif // MATRIZ_HPP
```

Y en el .cpp con el código de las operaciones(no pongo todas para no hacerlo largo):

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>


// COMPLEJIDAD: O(F*C)

Matriz::Matriz()
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = 0; // Valor int, C++ lo convierte automáticamente a E.
    }
  }
}

template <typename ModificaElemento>//esta viene ya con template, pero no la del TAD
void Matriz::modificar(ModificaElemento modifica_elemento)
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = modifica_elemento(elementos_[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

Matriz& Matriz::operator=(Matriz& m)
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = m.elementos_[i][j];
    }
  }

  return (*this);
}
```

**¿Como hago para crear la template y que el TAD sea genérico?**

> Se que por ejemplo en la clase hay que añadir:
>
> ```
> template<typename E, int F, int C>//añadido para el tipo generico y el numero de filas y columnas
> class Matriz
> {
> public:
>    //codigo
> private:
>    //codigo
> };
> ```
>
> Pero las operaciones del .cpp no se como modificarlas para que sean
>   genéricas.

PD: el código de prueba de las operaciones no creo necesario adjuntarle, pero si alguien que responda lo cree necesario, editaré la pregunta para añadirlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una nota inicial, en C++ acostumbra a utilizar `const [tipo]` en vez de `#define`. `#define` no tiene tipo alguno y eso puede dar lugar a errores dificiles de localizar.

Bien, hablando ahora de tu plantilla. Las plantillas tienen varias particularidades (te enumero un par de ellas):

- Tienen tipos genéricos (no es que no se sepa nunca el tipo concreto, sino que el mismo se determina cuando se instancia la plantilla)
- Todo el código **tiene que estar en la cabecera**. Dado que el compilador únicamente genera código de plantillas segun encuentra usos de las mismas es imprescindible que todo el código esté en la cabecera para que el compilador pueda generar el código binario correspondiente.

Dicho esto, lo primero que tienes que hacer es mover toda la implementación a la cabecera. Esto lo puedes hacer cortando y pegando o añadiendo un include al cpp:

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

// ...

// Al final!!!
#include "matriz.cpp"

#endif
```

En cualquier caso el resultado será el mismo y le permite al compilador encontrar el código fuente de la plantilla.

Ahora ¿cómo tratar con los tipos genéricos? Se hace exactamente igual que con tipos concretos. Te pongo algunos ejemplos:

declaracion de la clase y de la matriz interna:

```
template<class E, int F, int C>
class Matriz
{
  E elementos_[F][C];
};
```

Constructor:

```
template<class E, int F, int C>
Matriz<E,F,C>::Matriz()
//    ^^^^^^^ Importante!!!!
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Métodos que indican las filas y las columnas:

```
template<class E, int F, int C>
int Matriz<E,F,C>::filas() const
//                         ^^^^^ acostumbra a usar const en funciones
//                               que no modifican el objeto
{ return F; }


template<class E, int F, int C>
int Matriz<E,F,C>::columnas() const
{ return C; }
```

Operador de asignación

```
template<class E, int F, int C>
Matriz<E,F,C>& Matriz<E,F,C>::operator=(Matriz<E,F,C>& m)
{
  for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elementos_[i][j] = m.elementos_[i][j];
    }
  }

  return (*this);
}
```

Nota que, en este caso, solo podrás hacer asignaciones sobre plantillas exactamente del mismo tipo:

```
Matriz<int,5,5> m1, m2;
Matriz<float,5,5> m3;
Matriz<int,2,2> m4;

m1 = m2; // ok
m1 = m3; // error de compilacion
m1 = m4; // error de compilacion
```

Comment: Sí pero si hago esto último que indicas en la sobrecarga del operador `=`, me lanza este error:  `invalid use of template-name 'Matriz' without an argument list
 Matriz& Matriz<E,F,C>::operator=(Matriz& m)
 `

Comment: @AguaSal Fíjate que ese `Matriz` que tienes como argumento también va a ser una plantilla...ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: Una plantilla distinta o especifico la que ya tengo?

Comment: @Aguasal Revisa la respuesta, que está editada

Comment: Claro, yo le estaba quitando `<E,F,C>` a la clase y poniéndosela al argumento... gracias

Comment: En `m1=m4` ¿daría error de compilación o saltaría la función iguales que te dicen si lo son o no?, son del mismo tipo pero no tienen las mismas dimensiones.

Comment: @AguaSal error de compilación. Cada especialización de la plantilla genera una clase única... `Matriz<int,5,5>` y `Matriz<float,5,5>` no tienen herencia común y a ojos del compilador son tan parecidas como `int` y `std::string`.

Comment: En todas las operaciones que tengan un `Matriz<E,F,C>::ejemplo(Matriz m, Matriz& salida){//Codigo}` también son plantilla estos argumentos?

Comment: @AguaSal exacto